# How to change the default project directory (folder) in Netbeans 6.9?

Tags: java, netbeans, default, directory

How to change the default project directory in Netbeans 6.9 for Java SE\ME\EE?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think you can make it module-specific but you can set it as follows:

1. Close NetBeans
2. Find the `projectui.properties` file. For me (Windows) it was under `C:\Documents and Settings\Catchwa\.netbeans\6.9\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties`
3. The `projectsFolder=C:\\NetBeansProjects` variable is I think what you want to change.

Comment: unfortunately I can not find that variable in my projectui.properties

maybe I should create it?

Comment: In Linux, the `projectui.properties` file is in `$HOME/.netbeans/$VERSION/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules` where `$VERSION` is the full NB version number.

Comment: OSX (Don't forget to change version number depending on your installed version. Mine is 8.2): /Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/8.2/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties

Comment: For more recent versions of windows (Vista & later) and NetBeans, look in %APPDATA%\NetBeans\<nbversion>\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules, eg C:\Users\jla\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules

Comment: Strangely for me, this didn't seem to work... I had to reinstall NetBeans and reset the default root project directory from the initial startup screen. It may have been because I was using a special build of NetBeans for a school course.

Comment: @GDP2 or maybe because this answer is 12 years old :)

Answer (score 26):

I found mine in a slightly different location (Windows 7 64-bit using Netbeans 7.2):

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties

Comment: Also noteworthy: if you use SVN, you can edit `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.x\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\subversion.properties` and set `checkoutStep.checkoutDirectory` to change the default checkout path.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, "projectui.properties" file was not at that path (at least for the latest version of Netbeans 7.3 in an enterprise/network-managed security 64-bit Windows 7 setting)... so see my workaround below if you had the same problem.

Comment: Tested and working on 8.0.2 too.
you do not see the C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\<netbeans version>\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties in a clean netbeans install , you have to create a one project first then the file will appear.
Note** Path  
C:\Program Files\<netbeans version>\etc\netbeans.conf is a different file do not confuse it with C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\<netbeans version>\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties.

Comment: As a shorthand when navigating, use:
%APPDATA%\Netbeans\ (etc)

Answer (score 7):

Slightly different way of doing it for NetBeans 7.3 latest release (at least for Windows 7, 64-bit). Search your system for *netbeans.conf* (from explorer window) or go to its default install location:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\etc\netbeans.conf
```

Look for *netbeans.conf* on Mac OS X:

```
find / -name "netbeans.conf" -print &
```

Look for *netbeans.conf* in Linux:

```
sudo find / -name "netbeans.conf" 2> /dev/null
```

---

Then edit the *netbeans.conf* file to replace the *userdir* line:

```
netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/7.3"
```

With your new projects directory/folder path:

```
 netbeans_default_userdir="C:/APPS/netbeans/"
```

-OR-

```
 netbeans_default_userdir="\Applicatons\netbeans\"
```

(NOTE: if you have trouble in Windows in a network managed security environment, you'll need admin access to make this change. Open the file using your editor's ".exe" directly by right-clicking the launcher file and clicking "Run as Administrator", I had to do this for Notepad++ because it said "Another application is using the file", but in fact it was just locked to non-admin users).

This changes the default [userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) which stores user-specific IDE settings, but not the default project folder/directory. Next, you need to open NetBeans IDE with the new IDE settings and start to create a new Java project (then cancel after second screen in project creation wizard). It will now create a new **projectui.properties** file in the *userdir* you set; this is the file that wasn't found before this workaround that you need to edit as per the other suggestions. Mine was located here after these changes:

```
C:\APPS\netbeans\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules
```

Finally, you've reached the finish line and can change the **projectsFolder** property value to the path you want, if you don't see a line for **projectsFolder** then simply type or paste one in at the bottom of the file to point to your path where you want NetBeans to store projects by default, such as:

```
 projectsFolder=C:/APPS/projects/
```

-OR-

```
 projectsFolder=\Applicatons\projects\
```

Wow, that's alot of settings changes but it finally works for me the way I wanted it to,  being able to switch my IDE back and forth between a local workspace and a network workspace using my username space on the corporate LAN just by changing **projectsFolder** property value in the **projectui.properties** folder.

NOTE:
On Linux or Mac you might not need the first step of modifying *netbeans.conf* as the **projectui.properties** should be as follows (may vary by OS version):
 *$HOME/.netbeans/7.3/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties*

Comment: Note: change `netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/7.3"` not recommended it will break your IDE for in case if you have version 12

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows 7, logged in under AD, the projectui.properties file's directory was under the parent folder listed in the `USERPROFILE` environment variable (type `set` in a command prompt window):

```
C:\Users\my_login_name\\.netbeans\7.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties
```

It was not in the directories pointed at by the HOME or APPDATA variables.

Changed `projectsFolder` value to new location, restarted NetBeans and default folder for new projects was in the new location. It worked!

Answer (score 4):

In linux/Ubuntu

1. View hidden files in home directory (press ctrl+H on /home folder).
2. .netbeans\7.3\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties

Update the following content in **projectui.properties** file

```
projectsFolder=/home/folder/NB
```

Comment: Thanks this help me :)

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions, right-click on the project you want to move in the 'Projects' tab, and then click 'Move'. This will allow you to move the project to a new directory.

Answer (score -2):

In windows 7 64 bit properties file can be found under c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\ folder

Comment: Duplication of a previous answer

Comment: and its incomplete