# Netbeans 7.2.1 - Default project directory per project category

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, default

First of all, I have already saw the question [How to change the default project directory (folder) in Netbeans 6.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3077531/851432) I have edited the value of `projectsFolder` variable in `projectui.properties` file to change the default project directory, and it worked.

The problem with this is that it is a global change, meaning that, every project category (Java, Android, PHP, etc., ) will now use this directory as the default projects directory. But, I would like to have separate default directories, such as `~/Development/Andoid` for Android projects, `~/Development/Java` for Java projects, `~/Development/PHP` for PHP projects. I know that most probably I am here for a disappointment, but who knows!

*So, is there any trick or hack that you aware of to do this?*