# how do i change default sources folder in Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: netbeans-7

Does anybody know how to change the default sources folder in Netbeans 7.1.2

I've looked through the files but can't seem to locate where the default directory is stored - I have been through the forums but can't find anything useful..?

currently C:\Users\wayne\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject7

I have read that if you select a different directory then that becomes the default - this is not the case on my installation

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077531/how-to-change-the-default-project-directory-folder-in-netbeans-6-9) worked for version 6.9, not sure if it still does for 7.1.2.

Comment: @Dangerosking yes I found that answer - but 7.1.2 doesn't have the same file structure...? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7 or vista, you are gonna find it here `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.1.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties`.

However if you you are using windowsXP remember the `USERPROFILE` enviromental variable is not Users but rather Documents and Settings. Enviromental variables change depending on the operating system you are using. To know whats the `USERPROFILE` variable for yours just open a command prompt window and type `SET USERPROFILE`. Or you can simply type `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\$ENTER_YOUR_NETBEANS_VERSION_NUMBER_HERE\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.properties` and that will send you to the correct directory.

Comment: mine seems to be in C:\Users\wayne\.netbeans\7.1.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules there is a file called projectui which seems to include lastopened - recentprojects etc. but no ref to the default source directory..? thanks for your help

Comment: found it - it was not set to the default projects file path - so i changed it and saved it it but does not work when i re-open the file its back to the original setting - going to give up as its not a big deal - but i am surprised that its so difficult to change this setting ...!  thanks

Comment: Np mate, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple.

```
"C:\Users\wayne\.netbeans\7.1.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules there is a file called projectui"
```

is right on the money, but he forgot one detail that you need to keep in mind for changing the directory. If you want to set the default project folder to (in my case):

```
"C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot"
```

then you have to double the slashes. Instead of the above link you have to put:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\glassfish-3.1.2.2\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\docroot"
```

*without spaces. I had it that way originally but it hid one of each of them.*

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions, right-click on the project you want to move in the 'Projects' tab, and then click 'Move'. This will allow you to move the project to a new directory.

Answer (score -1):

Tip!  I found (on Windows 7) that the AppData folder is hidden, so doesn't appear in windows explorer files by default . 
To make it visible, open a window for the USERPROFILE directory as above, and use

- Organize ->
- Folder and Search Options ->
- View (tab) ->
- Advanced settings list ->
- Hidden files and folders radio button to show them.

(Or you can open it via search or run if you type it right)
I hope that saves you the several hours it cost me...

Comment: has it anything to do with asked question?