# Where is the home folder of the NetBeans project?

Tags: java

Am running a code that should be in a home folder but it not getting the files. where is the home folder for the NetBeans project so that I can paste that file there?

run:
courses.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077531/how-to-change-the-default-project-directory-folder-in-netbeans-6-9/3082720)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know exactly where your particular project home folder is located within your system then:

- Right-click on the project name within the (left) **Projects** pane
  in NetBeans;
- From the drop-down menu, select **Properties** located at the bottom.
  The **Project Properties** window will be displayed;
- Select the **Sources** list item (usually at the top of list) within
  the (left) **Categories** pane of the Properties Window.
- To the top-right of the Properties Window you can see the **Project
  Folder** property. What is displayed within that text field is the
  home location for your project.